# Incrementing in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I have json in my controller (will be moved) that is basically: id, questionName, answer.

I want to show each question in the code below. One question at a time. Upon clicking on the A links for yes/no I want the question to move on to the next.

I was hoping I could increment using "count" with an initial 0 which is the id relating to the json, and it would subsequently increase till the last question. This however doesn't seem to work; or at least my implementation doesn't.

I hope that's clear enough. It's hard to explain.

```
  <div class="row" id="dropdown" ng-controller="testYourself">
      <div id="q" class="cta1_content ugh" style="display:none;">
         <div ng-repeat="data in quiz" ng-show="count==0" data-ng-init="count=0">
            <h2 class="text-center">{{data.name}}</h2>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-md-offset-3 text-center yesno">
                <a href="#" class="q" data-question="{{count}}" data-answer="1" ng-click="count=count+1">
                    <span class="cta_next"><i class="icon ion-checkmark-round"></i></span>
                </a>
           </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 text-center yesno">
              <a href="#" class="q" data-question="{{count}}" data-answer="0" ng-click="count=count+1">
                <span class="cta_next"><i class="icon ion-close-round"></i></span>
              </a>
          </div>
       </div>                
    </div>
  </div>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
app.controller('testYourself', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.quiz = [
{id:0, name:"q1", answer: [{0: 'a', 1: 'b}], weight:25}
];
```

The id's are unnecessary to me, but added to try and do what I was trying. (I am 2 days new to Angular).

Thank you

**UPDATE
------**

```
<div id="q" class="cta1_content ugh" ng-controller="testYourself" data-ng-init="count=0">
    <div ng-repeat="data in quiz" ng-show="data.id==count">
        <h2 class="text-center">{{ data.name }} {{count}}</h2>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-md-offset-3 text-center yesno">
            <a href="#" class="q" data-question="{{data.id}}" data-answer="1" ng-click="count=count+1">
                <span class="cta_next"><i class="icon ion-checkmark-round"></i></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 text-center yesno">
            <a href="#" class="q" data-question="{{data.id}}" data-answer="0" ng-click="count=count+1">
                <span class="cta_next"><i class="icon ion-close-round"></i></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: post your controller code, it's difficult to figure it out without the  actual code

Comment: Thank you. Have updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are quit a number of things going on here.

1. Many syntax errors in your posted js code.  So if that is pasted from your actual code, consider adding necessary braces, brackets, and quotes.
2. There is an inline style on #q.  This means that none of the contents are visible.  With angular, all you need is ng-show, and the library will take care of the rest.  So get rid of that, and you should see question 1.
3. You probably want to put the ng-init on an element like #q.  ng-repeat creates a new scope, so your count here is in the scope of the repeat rather than the scope of the controller (which is probably what you want).

Hope that helps.

Comment: 1. You are quite right and that was down to ripping code out. The js is valid.
2. I had originally implemented this in jQuery.
3. I have updated my code above.

The counting loop is correctly updating the "data-question" lines, but is not changing the ng-show="data.id==count" which is what changes which question is shown.

Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Upon loading the first question appears correctly. Then clicking on one of the yes/no links causes the question to disappear and no further to be rendered.

Comment: I'm thinking that the `count` you are incrementing is in the scope ng-repeat.  Try `$parent.count++`